# Board soldered airtight capsule

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, mechanical-assembly

Mechanical Engineer here, not an EE.

I have some environmental sensors that need to be a part of a flow path.
It occurred to me that it might be possible to have a metal "can" that sealed to the board around the sensors by sodler, providing a gas-tight connection. The current solution uses a plastic part with an oring and through the board screws, and it doesn't work well, as a bonus.

How would I communicate this to the EE's doing the board layout?

Ideally, there would be a lid like rf shields that could be snapped on and off and be gas-tight when on.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic. Be more specific, what do you mean by how would I communicate *this*... what is "this". If you have a question about how would I construct an RF shield that's sealed then that would be a better question. PCB's aren't really a good material to seal to.

Comment: You communicate to the EEs by sitting down with them, explaining your problem, sharing some sketches, and answering their questions. As always.

Comment: PCB technology is not generally gas-tight.  If you need that you are typically looking at an enclosure, fancy gas tight modules (in aerospace etc) may have enclosures laser welded shut.

Comment: @laptop2d How would you construct an RF shield that's gas-tight?

Comment: @Mordecai what pressure do you need to seal?

Comment: 50 millibar (20 inches of water)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a can, preferably made with a continuous external flange,  it could be soldered to a mating copper loop on the board. However vias would represent holes through the board under the can. Blind and buried vias are possible, but add to cost and NRE.

You would communicate this with drawings following a meeting to discuss options.

Such a seal would not be considered hermetic, you’d want ceramic and feedthroughs etc. for that.

Comment: I think the via problem would be solved by filling/capping with solder.